# Scaling Number of Passed Values in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pass-by-value

I an writing an XML Writer and have it so that it can write this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mappings>
    <entry name="Iasanator">
        <item code="Red">He Needs Help</item>
    </entry>
</mappings>
```

...But I need to be able to put a varying number of **id="whatever"** statements passing into the XMLWriter.WriteHeader(*# of these needs to scale*) sub.

```
<header id="whatever" href="this" code="that" name="and so on".......>
```

I can put up to two thanks to overloads subs, but how do I put in like... 15 or something without writing separate overloads subs for each number of possible cases?

EDIT: Nkvu, I solved the problem on my own, then read that you had a similar idea. **Great Minds Think Alike.** I used a type of array like you suggested except I used a dictionary list where "parameters = New Dictionary(Of String, String)".

The entire XML Writer can be found at: http://pastebin.com/03TuX0Pd

If you find some of it confusing, (I'm not the best at commenting stuff) feel free to comment and ask a question. I'll be glad to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to post the VB.NET code that you have so far?

Broadly, I can think of two options:

### Members with a Variable Number of Parameters

You might want something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229008%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you pass in a variable number of parameters to your sub and then it iterates over them and decides what to do with it.

Each parameter could be your header id (if it was a string or some base type like an integer) or you could pass in a class/complex type (e.g. you could have a `Header` class which has properties for the ID, href, code, name etc).

For the complex type, your signature would look something like:

```
Public Sub DoStuff(ParamArray list() as HeaderClass)
```

And you would call it similar to:

```
DoStuff(headerObj1, headerObj2, headerObj3)
```

Where headerObj1 etc are objects which you have created previously

### Pass in an array/list/collection

You could also just form a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or other collection type and pass it into your sub.

So your sub signature would look like:

```
Public Sub DoStuff(headers as List(of HeaderClass))
```

And you would call it similar to:

```
Dim headerList As List(Of HeaderClass) = New List(Of HeaderClass)
headerList.Add(headerObj1)
headerList.Add(headerObj2)
headerList.Add(headerObj3)

DoStuff(headerList)
```

Your sub could then iterate over the list and do what needs to be done.